# Update feature style outside a mapInteraction function

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am creating an accessible way of navigating the features on an Openlayers map. This is done by creating a ul of buttons, where each button has the id of a **feature** displayed on the map as it's value.

Whenever a button in the ul is focused i am able to show a title **Overlay** of the feature on the map, and am also able to open the feature's popup **Overlay** on keyDown, however i cannot change the style of the given feature using for example:

```
feature.setStyle(new Style({...style...})
```

This given code doesn't cause an update of the feature on the map and i am concerned it happens because it is outside an Openlayers mapInteraciton (Select condition) function.

Any way i can trigger a style change outside the given Openlayers conditions?

Comment: That should work as in https://codesandbox.io/s/wms-tiled-forked-b60egz?file=/main.js

Comment: First of all thank you for the great example. I am setting the new style directly on the feature as you do, however somehow it isn't updating. So maybe my code is affected from something else..